# Quarter-wave stacks and rejection filters to protect flight crews' vision from visible laser pointers

Tags: optics, laser

I would like to know how  the physics(and possibly mathematics) for how  quarter-wave stacks could be utilized to make an ideal rejection filter that rejects all visible coherent green or blue or red laser light, not at the same time, in a given narrow spectral wavelength range (10 nanometers to 20 nanometers wide) and transmits everything else within the visible light band.

I have read some optics books on the analysis of quarter wave plates for normal incidence. I analyzed  how the Boeing 757 aircraft's nose geometry forces incoming laser rays aimed from the ground on approach to hit the cockpit window at large angles of incidence and high orders of interference. If you would like to see this analysis , I will post it as an image. So, I would be interested in how to analyze the blocking and transmission properties of quarter-wave stacks at large angles of incidence.

Also, I would like to know the relationship between coherence length of visible light laser pointer beams and the distance between quarter wave plates so we could discriminate between coherent and incoherent light over a very narrow wavelength range.

The reason I ask this question is because I read Fred Goldstein's chapter, Optical Filters , in the book "Geometrical and Instrumental Optics" edited by Daniel Malacara and published by Academic Press in 1988. In Section 6.3.4  , page 294 , Fred Goldstein wrote that, "There is interest in filters which reject in an extremely narrow spectral regions. These could be superior to current filters utilized for eye protection near lasers. In theory, such filters can be constructed from a great number of quarter-wave layers of materials with nearly identical indices.[EDIT June 8 2016 Why?] Inhomogenous films with periodic index variations represent another possiblity. [EDIT June 8 2016 Why?]"

I believe that matrix and Fourier transform formalism may be necessary here.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I thought you have your "technology" under control? You said you were going to present your "whiteboard formulas" to the FAA... and, yet, here you are, again, asking about trivial stuff that you can't seem to figure out on your own. :-) Remember what I told you about invalidating any possibility to patent if you keep talking about in public?

Comment: @Curious One, Thank you for your comment.  I can show you whiteboard formulas I derived last week. The real patent the FAA would be interested in is an advanced semiconductor fabrication of a photonics circuit which could calculate a solution to an original system of equations. May I ask why you think I am asking about trivial stuff here?

Comment: The FAA isn't interested in any patents, but that's something you can much better "discuss" over at the aviation SE.

Comment: There are already great optical coatings used for laser safety glasses (lg7, here http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=762) which are having the needed characteristics. Dolby 3D is also based on dichroic filteres. Dielectric laser filters are also state of the art since decades. Much work was put into dielectric coatings since 1988...

Comment: @user_na., What is the physics behind "The filter is made by coating a transparent substrate with optical films. The optical thickness of each film layer of the coating exceeds the coherence length of sunlight and many artificial  sources, but not the coherence length of most laser sources, resulting in a thick-film filter that discriminates between coherent and incoherent light over broad wavelength ranges. Rudimentary calculations show that by using this type of filter, a contrast ratio in excess of 1000 between coherent and incoherent light is possible" Thank you.

Comment: @user_na, Thank you for pointing out the progress in dielectric coatings, We need  a tunable notch filter placed on top the cockpit windshield . Its output signal would only be an incoherent light signal containing a view of the airport runway on approach projected on a Planar transparent display.What is the best physics approach for tackling this requirement?

Comment: Do you have a source where you can buy a big enough block of single-crystal quartz (or some other birefringent crystal) to carve a cockpit window out of?

Comment: @ThePhoton, Thank you for your excellent comment.  One of  the advantages of birefrigent  filters over interference filters  is the ease with which they can be tuned. Another advantage of birefrigent  filters is the large field of view that it is possible to obtain. Is that the reason we should carve a cockpit window out of a big enough block of  single-crystal quartz (or some other birefringent crystal)?

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, I just added  7  images volume of vulnerability analysis for large incidence angles and Bragg's law of diffraction gratings for you to correct and take to the next level of complexity in your spare time to the original question, You are a remarkable engineer and physicist. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for "I would like to know how the physics": that question is too broad to answer; I'd suggest that you get a book on Fourier optics and work through it by solving the exercise problems - you can ask for hints to solve the exercises here on Physics SE.

I'll answer the more specific questions and address some misconceptions.

As for "coherent light": coherence of light and laser beams is often misunderstood, partially because there are different definitions of coherence, depending on what aspect of the light you're interested in. A laser beam has *transversal coherence*, which means that the light propagates as a beam.  A laser typically also has *longitudinal coherence*, which is a measure for its wavelength bandwidth (or rather, the inverse of of its wavelength bandwidth).

Any filtering optics will not distinguish between a ray of light from a green laser or a ray of light from a green lightbulb. All you can do is trying to select for direction of the ray and wavelength of the ray.

For a quarter-wave stack: it's not a series of quarter-wave plates that you can arrange by hand. It's a series of layers, each of them with a thickness $\lambda/(4n)$, where $n$ is the refractive index of the layer and without air gaps in between (unless you count the air gap as a layer by itself). The layers must alternate between high and low refractive indices. For example, if a layer refractive index is 1.5 and the wavelength to reflect is 532 nm, you need a layer of 89 nm thickness. For more on the topic: [Wikipedia: dielectric mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror); how to calculate: [Wikipedia: transfer-matrix method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method_%28optics%29). You can also calculate it for non-normal incidence, but for that you'll have to get an advanced optics book.

I suppose that you would want the mirror/filter to be automatically adjustable in case of an incident laser beam. Such a variable dielectric mirror would need to adapt itself to a specific wavelength and specific angle of incidence. If you want to keep the mirror fixed in orientation, you will need to adjust the refractive index and/or the thickness of the layers by a substantial amount (a factor 2 or so). I don't think that this is possible in practice.

Comment: And even then, that quarter-wave stack is optimized for a certain fixed angle of incidence, while pilots generally need to see all around them.

Comment: @JonCuster I suppose that the idea is that you have a sensor that detects a laser beam and then adjusts the filter within milliseconds, before the pilot is dazzled.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, Thank you for your excellent answer which I enjoyed reading. This evening I will post several comments on your answer. I hope you can respond to these comments.

Comment: @Jon Custer, Thank you for your great comment. If  the quarter-wave stack needs to be  optimized for a certain fixed angle of incidence, how much the transmissivity deteriorate once a ray deviates from the fixed angle of incidence.?Are there alternate optical structures for implementing rejection filters?

Comment: @Frank - that is a pretty basic optics question, with an intro in the Wikipedia article reference above on the transfer-matrix method. You seem very excited about your idea. I would suggest stepping back and looking at what is already out there frpm a business point of view (multi-wavelength anti-dazzle products are a reality), and dig deeper in to understanding more about optical physics (both active and passive devices).

Comment: @Jon Custer,Thank you for your reply.  Multi-wavelength  anti-dazzle products such as multi-wavelength anti-dazzle products  are not popular with Boeing 757 pilots.

Comment: @Frank, unless something is incorrect in my answer, I'd like to leave the this Q&A for what it is.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, Thank you for your comment. In your answer, it states that "Any filtering optics will not distinguish between a ray of light from a green laser or a ray of light from a green lightbulb. All you can do is trying to select for direction of the ray and wavelength of the ray." Please read this URL http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/2670/1/2670.pdf, "Detection of coherent light in an incoherent background" and let me know if your statement in your answer is still correct or needs to be changed.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, You are the smartest scientist on this Stack Exchange. Please critique this article which I just read, Band-Limited Filters and Bragg Reflectors in Perturbed Defect Nanostructures of Chiral Sculpted Thin Films, http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=7445154&filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A7457727%29, in light of the Boeing 757 cockpit window volume of vulnerability to a 100 milliwatt visible light laser pointer  on approach, 100 meters , from the runway? Or, should I create another question on Engineering Stack Exchange? Thank you.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, May I ask you to please comment briefly on my question and answer, http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/how-does-the-michelson-interferometer-measure-the-self-coherence-function-of-coh? Could a Fabry-Perot interferometer be used instead of a Michelson interferometer for measuring the self coherence function of coherent laser light combined with a background of incoherent light? Thank you.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys, You are a genius. I have not heard from you in 2 weeks. Please take a look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264030/physics-of-detection-of-coherent-light-in-an-incoherent-background-using-the-mor